# Should it be *foam* or *a foam*?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

> We approached the edge of the cliff and peered down. It was completely
>   dark, except for a faint, almost invisible white foam.

Should it be

> a faint, almost invisible white foam.

Or

> faint, almost invisible white foam.

Comment: You mean "should foam be used as a count noun or a mass noun". Neither of your versions uses the plural _foams_. I think the sentence is confusing: the presence of white foam does not in any way present an exception to it being completely dark. Maybe something like "It was so dark that we couldn't see anything except a white foam".

Comment: I think that what's dark is the _water,_ except for the foam. (Native AmE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foam is usually a mass (noncount; uncountable) noun.

While we normally treat mass nouns as singular (*that is foam* NOT* *those are foam*), the issue you raise is whether or not to use the indefinite article, *a/an*. We normally do not use *a/an* with mass nouns (NOT* a milk), but we do use them when we talk about a particular part or instance of one (a [glass of] milk; a [moment in] time).

In this particular context, when we look down, we do not see foam in general, but we see perhaps a "sheet" of foam. That kind of usage would treat foam as a count or countable noun. Although we can leave out "sheet" (or whatever), most writers would choose:

> ...a faint, almost invisible white foam.

(I've revised this answer thanks to oerkelens's comment below.)

Comment: As a mass noun, you do not use the article. You say it's a mass noun, and in your sentence you use it as a count noun. I would use it as a count noun too in this case, but your first sentence squarely contradicts your chosen line.

Comment: I was just seeing that and revising. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> We approached the edge of the cliff and peered down. It was completely dark, except for a faint, almost invisible white foam.

As others have said *foam* is usually a mass noun. So is coffee. But I once went to a local coffee house, and they had **a** coffee there that I highly recommend. This shows we can use *a* with a mass noun when referring to a certain/specific type of that substance. **A** gross, green putrid milk was what poured out of the 3-month-old milk bottle.